# I am trying to use this code sHdrMetadataFormatCurrentlySupported(HdrMetadataFormat.HDR10);

Tags: c#, uwp, television, xbox-one

I am using below code to check hdr compatibility

```
var displayInfo = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
var colorInfo = displayInfo.GetAdvancedColorInfo();
var isHDRSupported = colorInfo.IsHdrMetadataFormatCurrentlySupported(HdrMetadataFormat.HDR10);
```

I have hdr display screen but that code always returns false though it is an HDR scree. Please suggest some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format you code. Is the API you are using part of an external library or it is your implementation? Provide the code if it is yours.

Comment: this is c# code and api provided by Microsoft only.

Comment: Did a search on that function, looks like it is undocumented (in [.NET API browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/index?term=HdrMetadataFormat)) but it does exists [in UWP API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/index?term=HdrMetadataFormat). Added edit suggestion fot that tag.

Comment: I wonder if the screen does expose HDR metadata correctly or if your windows 10 is in up to date [Device family Windows 10, version 1803 & API contract v.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.hdrmetadataformat)

Comment: What screen are you using? How do you know it is HDR? What driver are you using for the screen?

Comment: I have UWP app for Xbox which has windows 10.0.17763.4088. I have connected my xbox to Samsung 2018 TV and it's a hdr tv.

Comment: What is the exact model of the TV?

Comment: Samsung 2018 model UE43NU7400

Answer (score 0):

UWP on Xbox One does not support HDR10 output.

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-and-uwp-on-xbox-one/)